# How to block test while select statement processes channel operation for the purpose of unit testing?

Tags: go, testing, channel

I'm trying to cover a version of the simplified example below with unit tests. I want to test both adding and removing items from the container. The test assertion is running (and failing) before the `select` statement has received and processed the value sent to the channel.

Is there a way to test these cases without modifying the non-test code to include some kind of wait group or add a response channel?

```
package main

import "testing"

type Container struct {
    items  map[*Item]bool
    add    chan *Item
    remove chan *Item
}

type Item struct {
    name string
}

func (c *Container) run() {
    for {
        select {
        case item := <-c.add:
            c.items[item] = true
        case item := <-c.remove:
            delete(c.items, item)
        }
    }
}

func TestAddItem(t *testing.T) {
    container := &Container{
        items:  make(map[*Item]bool),
        add:    make(chan *Item),
        remove: make(chan *Item),
    }
    go container.run()

    if len(container.items) > 0 {
        t.Errorf("Container shouldn't contain anything yet")
    }

    container.add <- &Item{name: "Thing"}

    if len(container.items) != 1 {
        t.Errorf("Container should have 1 item, actually has %d.", len(container.items))
    }
}

func TestRemoveItem(t *testing.T) {
    container := &Container{
        items:  make(map[*Item]bool),
        add:    make(chan *Item),
        remove: make(chan *Item),
    }
    go container.run()

    item := &Item{name: "Thing"}
    container.add <- item

    if len(container.items) != 1 {
        t.Errorf("Container should have 1 item, actually has %d.", len(container.items))
    }

    container.remove <- item

    if len(container.items) != 0 {
        t.Errorf("Container should have 0 items, actually has %d.", len(container.items))
    }
}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/2rbZh-4GOWp

Comment: I assume this is a contrived example since this unit test doesn't prove anything other than that the Go language itself works. Concurrency code is hard to test in any language; typically you'd want to extract the business logic into a synchronous function which gets called concurrently, so that you can test the business logic in a unit test and keep the concurrency code so simple it doesn't need a test. Alternatively you could just add a `time.Sleep` after the channel ops and call it a day.

Comment: Correct, a contrived example. I just wondered if there was a more "correct" way to block before the (currently) failing test assertion than adding a `time.Sleep`.

Comment: The program has a data race.  Fix by adding a race-free way to method to get the length of the map. https://go.dev/play/p/Sek8oO-8XoS

Comment: You have a data race, adding `time.Sleep` is absolutely not correct. If you want to check `items`, you need additional synchronization'

Comment: Would this be an idiomatic way of synchronising the processing of the container channels with test assertions? The `done` channels _can_ be ignored outside of the testing context, I think? https://go.dev/play/p/s-Nx3V2fkNa

Comment: @Anonymous The `done` channel cannot be ignored.  To see why, run the test [with the `<-item.done` statements commented out](https://go.dev/play/p/lDPXmzPEUL-).   The least intrusive way to test the code in the question is to [add a race-free method for getting the length of the map](https://go.dev/play/p/Sek8oO-8XoS).   You may reasons to use a goroutine and channels. Based on the information in the question alone, the idiomatic solution [is to use a mutex](https://go.dev/play/p/Estnv8EYjID).

Comment: Thanks @RedBlue (and others). Apologies, I didn't mean not to acknowledge your original reply. The more I look at your solution with the race-free method, the more it makes sense.